# changing height of a custom keyboard when rotating

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, uikeyboard, screen-rotation

I have a customized keyboard created by code, it is a unique input view for a specific textfield. I implement this in my project:

```swift
let keyboardContainerView = KBContainerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.5))
keyboardContainerView.addSubview(myKeyboardView)
textfield.inputView = keyboardContainerView
```

The KBContainerView is a UIView but has a function, that is when detected device rotation, the frame change. It's quite simple.

```swift
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateFrame), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
    
@objc func updateFrame() {
    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.5)
}
```

But I found that though the keyboard container view is changed, as I printed it on the command line but the size of keyboard seems does not change. Here is a gif.

[image: Portrait]

Start from a landscape view does not change the height either.

[image: Landscape]

To fix this problem I tried to use `autoresizingMasks` on the input view but things get worse,  the keyboard height is wrong when starts the app. The navigation bar also covered keyboard in landscapeview.

[image: Adding the autoresizingMasks]

In my project, I **did not** wrote a `UIKeyboardviewController` for simplicity. What I am trying to achieve is that when rotating my device, the keyboard can **takes half space of the screen. (height is 0.5 * screen height)**

Is it because I wrote the change size action in the wrong place?

Comment: Unrelated, but you reference `UIKeyboardViewController`. I assume you meant [`UIInputViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputviewcontroller)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I get use the standard keyboard dimensions for my custom `inputView` using

```
autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

In this case, if you want it always to be 50% of the height, you might want to

- turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`;
- add your own constraints for width, height, centerX and bottom

For example, below is a simple input view that I've defined to be 50% of the height of the window with the following within the keyboard input `UIView` subclass:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    guard let superview = superview else { return }
    
    var lastView: UIView! = self
    while lastView.superview != nil {
        lastView = lastView.superview
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0),
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.widthAnchor),
        centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.centerXAnchor),
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}
```

Now I'm crawling up the view hierarchy to get the top level view. Perhaps you'd want to pass it the view that you want it to use for the height constraint. I just hate referring to `UIScreen.main` because sometimes our app won't have the full screen.

But let's not get lost in the details. The key is to use constraints and let the auto layout engine do everything for us. Then we don't have to respond to rotation events ourselves:

[image]

Comment: Hey Rob thank you for this beautifully working answer. What if we want the keyboard height to be something  in portrait and something else in landscape? I just asked a similar question would you mind checking it out? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using stack views to build up the entire numeric keypad as a custom InputView for text fields.

So the solution is to set stack view's size as orientation changes in layoutSubviews() and update intrinsicContentSize accordingly

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    mainStackView.frame.size = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: <dynamicHeight>)
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: <dynamicHeight>)
}
```

Ensure you've set autoresizingMask for your custom inputView and mainStackView

```
autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

I have created an extension to detect whether current orientation is Portrait of Landscape:

```
extension UIDevice {
  var isLandscapeMode: Bool {
    return (UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft) || (UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight) || (UIScreen.main.bounds.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
  }
}
```

Leaving my comment here in case someone needs it